# Bitwise operators in Python

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

not a native programmer here (medical background). I am looking for a bitwise operator that gives me the following results given the following conditions. The programming language is `Python` but that should not be too relevant:

```
condition1 condition2 result
0          1          0
1          1          1
1          0          1
0          0          1
```

Is this achievable with one operator alone? How would the code look like? I know it can be achieved with `if/else` statements but am interested in understanding new fields of programming.

Comment: Best I can think of is `~(condition1 ^ condition2) | condition1`

Comment: @0x5453: Thanks. How would that work?

Comment: For this example, `condition1 ^ condition2` would evaluate to `1010`.  `~` flips that to `0101`, then the `| condition1` fixes the third case to `0111`.

Comment: Your bio says "I do have 20+ years experience in programming, mainly in C, C++, PHP and Python with a bit of MySQL and JavaScript as well". I think you can safely call yourself a programmer.

Comment: It's everything except the first case `~condition1 & condition2`. So it's `condition1 | ~condition2`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Of course I am and I have a lot of experience. But I do not have a *theoretical* background, that is I do not know what an automata state machine is or deMorgan's rules. Simply because I did not study it but learned it on the way.

Comment: @khelwood: Mind posting an answer?

Comment: @Jan Certainly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected result is 1 for every case except the first.

The first case (where `condition1` is 0 and `condition2` is 1) is described by `~condition1 & condition2`.

The opposite of that expression is

```
condition1 | ~condition2
```

so this expression gives the expected result for every case.

---

As requested, some detail on the difference between logical boolean operations and bitwise operations.

If we have two boolean values A and B, and we want to perform an "or" operation on them, we use the Python operator `or` and we get back one boolean value.

If we have two integers A and B, and we want to perform a bitwise "or" operation on them,
we use the Python operator `|` and we get back an int whose bits are determined by the operation's action on each bit in A and B.

For instance

If A is 12 and B is 5, then they have the following bits:

```
A   = 1100
B   = 0101
A|B = 1101
```

In this case, the result `A|B` is 1101 binary, which is 13 decimal.

With the bitwise "not" operator the result is a little more complex to understand.

The binary representation of the number 1 is that the smallest bit is 1 and all the other bits are zero. So when you perform `~1`, you don't get zero. You get a number whose every bit is 1 except for the smallest, which is zero.

```
 1 = 00...001
~1 = 11...110
```

Because ints are stored in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), `11...110` is the binary representation of the number `-2`.

So though the boolean `not` operator gives you `not 1==0` (i.e. `not True==False`), the bitwise `~` operator gives you `~1 == -2`, since every individual bit gets flipped.

Comment: Where could I find additional information for deMorgan‘s rule.

Comment: On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), for instance

Comment: Is there a way to actually represent this in Python? `0 | ~1` gives `-2`.

Comment: @HTF If you want to use this in Python as a boolean (as opposed to bitwise) expression it would be `condition1 or not condition2`.

Comment: @khelwood: Could you elaborate a bit on the difference between bitwise and bool operators - this would turn a good answer into a gret one, imo.

Comment: @Jan I have made an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `condition1**condition2`

```
>>> 0**1
0
>>> 1**1
1
>>> 1**0
1
>>> 0**0
1
```

or more generally `condition1 OR (NOT condition2)`

Answer (score 1):

this is clearly `not (not A and B)`
usind De Morgan `A or not B`
In bitwise meaning `A | ~B`

`|` is or, `~` is invert (not)